# How to take two objects with the same values, and make it so that they are seen as one single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, filter

I am creating a multi-select dropdown component that allows for manual filtering. When the items are first displayed I am looping through an array of objects:

```
   customers = [
       {name: "Boe", city: "Scottsdale", state: "AZ", zip: 45454},
       {name: "Tom", city: "Austin", state: "TX", zip: 34323}
    ]
```

If the user selects the above customer from the dropdown without filtering, this is the object in the console:

```
 Object {name: "Boe", city: "Scottsdale", state: "AZ", zip: 46545, $$hashkey: "object 71"}
```

When the the manual filter is set, this allows the text the user types to filter the dropdown, to be passed outside the component. An example of a custom filter could look like this, which would most likely filter something from the server and then send back a new array of objects. So for example say the user typed in the letter "b" in the input, the above data would get filtered to show only "Boe" in the dropdown list, the matches array below would only hold "Boe"

```
 var matches = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < unfilteredCustomers.length; i++) {
     //filter it
 }
 //update the customers based on each letter that is typed
 $scope.customers = matches;
```

This then gets passed back into the component like so:

```
   <dropdown-select items="customers"></dropdown-select>
```

So initially, the customers being passed in is the first array of customers, once the user starts to type to filter the customers get updated and passed back into the component. If I filter and select the filtered row, here is what shows in the console:

```
Object {name: "Boe", city: "Scottsdale", state: "AZ", zip: 46545, $$hashkey: "object 170"}
```

The $$hashKey is changing. I realize I basically sending back in a new array that changes its reference from the original set of items. But the problem The functionality of the component is that if a user filters and makes a selection the dropdown opens back up to its original items. So the problem I'm having is once a user selects a filtered item, and the dropdown opens back up the user can select the same items again because "this.selectedItems.indexOf(selectedRow) === -1 doesn't see the filtered row as the same as when the dropdown is not filtered and a user makes a selection.

How can I get those two objects to be considered the exact same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if all the values of these objects are primitives

```
function areSameObjects(ob1, ob2){
    var areSame = false;

    if(Object.keys(ob1).length === Object.keys(ob2).length){
        delete ob1.$$hashkey;
        delete ob2.$$hashkey;
        areSame = Object.keys(ob1).reduce(function(state, key){
            state = Object.is(ob1[key],ob2[key]) && state;
            return state;
        }, true);
    }

    return areSame;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this does work. thanks. The only change I made was using the "delete" key on a angular property does not remove the property. It only removes properties you created yourself. In Angular you can use angular.toJson which removes the $$haskey property from the object. So I used "ob1 = angular.toJson(ob1)" to remove the $hashkey property.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a language-level feature. Instead, you must check for **value equality**. Lodash has a method that recursively checks all properties and values to see if everything matches https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual.

Alternatively, you can find a way to hash the objects, or maybe just `JSON.stringify` them both and compare those values.

Comment: Thanks Andy...I'm using angular.equals that should do the same thing. But the whole problem is those two objects I listed in my post aren't ever equal. Is that because the $$haskKey is different or is that because they are essentially two different arrays that contain the same object? I'm really trying to figure out how I can make those two objects above equal because right now angular.equals returns false when I filter and select a row, and the click on the same row when the dropdown is not filtered, which means they aren't the same thing. How can I get them to be viewed as the same?